# IDENTITY Column reset numbering

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with an `IDENTITY` column (`bigint`).

Let's say that the table contains 100 records, then the `IDENTITY` column will have values from 1-100.

If I delete some records in between, let's say deleted the row with identity values 3, 7, 18, 20.

I need to renumber the rows to start from 1 to 96, and the new record to continue from 97.

How to achieve that?

Comment: But I have that in a table of audit, no relations with other tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Jacob H has stated in the comments is completely right, an `IDENTITY` column is not designed to hold sequential values. If you `DELETE` a row, then you will be missing a number. Also, however, if an `INSERT` fails, a transaction is rollbacked, or (if you're on an older version of SQL Server) the server stops unexpectedly, then you will also observe the same issue. *(In older versions, SQL Server used to cache a range of Identities (1000). If the server unexpected stopped, then the cache would not be released, and thus the seed (at start up) would be the maximum value of the old cache +1.)*

If you need to get a sequential number, you'll need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your `SELECT` statement. You'd need something like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourIDColumn) AS SequentialIdentity
```

*Edit: If you wanted to have a more permanent way of getting the "Row Number", then you could create a `VIEW`, which has a column containing the value of your Sequential Identity from `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then, instead of referencing the Table in your queries, reference the View.*

Answer (score 1):

As @Jacob said in his comment, keys are not meant to be changed. Once a row have got a key (identity) it should remain the same until the row is deleted. I would instead suggest that you add a new column that you can use to store the number in.

Do note though that the new column needs to be maintained because everytime a row is deleted a gap in the number sequence. How often this needs to be done depends, maybe once a night by a scheduled job, or immediately using a database trigger.

You could also skip the entire problem by creating a row numbering column only when fetching data from the database. A query might look something like this:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY KeyColumn) AS test, * FROM MyOwnTable ORDER BY test
```